# android. как правильно подгрузить картинку в listview

Tags: android, listview

У меня есть `listview` заполненный с помощью MySimpleCursorAdapter(extends `SimpleCursorAdapter`).

Каждая строка(элемент) - кастомный `view`, состоящая из трех `imageview` и одного `textview`. Первая `imageview` может изменяться(пользователь может менять). Вторая и третья `imageview` - постоянные.

Проблема вот в чем: иногда неправильно загружается картинка в первую `imageview`.
Например: добавил я строку с пустой(дефолтной) картинкой - все хорошо. Потом добавил я строку со своей картинкой(загрузил ее из галереи) - тоже все хорошо. Потом снова добавил строку с пустой(дефолтной) картинкой - и тут все плохо. Вместо дефолтной картинки отобразилась моя(которая была во второй строке). Добавляю еще строку с пустой картинкой - 1 и 3 с дефолтными картинками, 2 и 4 с моей картинкой(хотя должна быть только 2).

При нажатии на картинку - в новом окне я открываю ее во весь экран - и тут все хорошо. Там где ДОЛЖНА быть дефолтная - открывается дефолтная, даже если в списке отображается неправильно. 
База заполнена правильно, проверял.
неправильно идет заполнение `listview`.

как правильно загрузить `imageview` в `listview`?

```
public class MySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {
   @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        getItem(position);
        lposition = position;
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        }


        avatarka = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_imageView_avatarka);


        avatarka.setTag(position);

        if(lCursor.moveToPosition(position)){
            if(lCursor.getString(lCursor.getColumnIndex(DB.KEY_IMG))==null){
                avatarka.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_photo_camera_white_48dp);
                avatarka.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                Log.d(MainActivity.MY_TAG, position+"-jopa");
            }
            else {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(lCursor.getString(lCursor.getColumnIndex(DB.KEY_IMG)));
                Log.d(MainActivity.MY_TAG, position + "" + lCursor.getString(lCursor.getColumnIndex(DB.KEY_IMG)));
                avatarka.setImageURI(uri);
                avatarka.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            }
        }

        avatarka.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: еще дополню - если создать большой `listview`, который не помещается на экран и начать его листать - то его тоже начинает глючить - `imageview` с дефолтными картинками начинают загружаться как попало(иногда дефолтными, а иногда из галереи, которые я были выбраны для других `imageview`)

Comment: Дополнения пишите редактируя вопрос, а не в комментарии.

Comment: в одном случае вы добавляете background, в другом src. При переиспользовании, видимо, у вас они накладываются и получается каша.

Comment: @YuraIvanov, к сожалению, нет. Но идея была интересной.

Comment: @PavelK я бы предложил переписать все в recyclerView и использовать Glide или Picasso для загрузки картинок.

Comment: Я бы даже сказал, что recyclerView вам необходим, дабы улучшить performance

Comment: Если добавляете background.ом, то можно обернуть ImageView, в Layout с нужным размером(как рамку), это избавит Вас от ряда проблем. И действительно использовать recyclerView будет здесь как минимум удобней, а если вы будете работать в обоих orientation: то увеличите производительность и избавитесь от ряда ошибок. Всё верно написано выше, Вам стоит переработать код.